# Notification Code is not working below sdkVersion 16

Tags: java, android, sdk, notifications

I wrote this methode

```
private void showVocNotification(String FR, String DE, String Language) {
String kleinerText = DE + "\nheißt auf " + Language + "\n" + FR; 
String grosserText = "Merk dir das für immer und ewig";


Intent i = new Intent(this, Remind.class);
i.setAction("de.bsv.taubenNotification");


PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);    

Notification notification  = new Notification.Builder(this)
.setContentTitle(grosserText)
.setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText(kleinerText)) 
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
.setAutoCancel(true).build();

NotificationManager mNM = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNM.notify("dashierIstdieID", 0, notification);
Log.d(Log_TAG, "Notified");
}
```

The Problem is, that it requires  android:minSdkVersion="16" (API-Level 16). As you probably know, many phones are still running Android 2.3 or 4.0.

I need to change the code, that It is possible to run the application with at least API Level 9.

This is your part because I failed on finding an alternative, or if you find something, I'd also be very happy about a Link to an explaination.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [NotificationCompat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.html) class instead of Notification. You can find it inside the compatibility library, and will handle all the compatibility/legacy stuff for you. Its Builder has the exact same usage as Notification.Builder as well

Comment: Awesome. I give it a try now.

Comment: Glad it did. If you have any issues with it, let me know

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
private void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {

int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
String appname = context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
Notification notification;
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
new Intent(context, myactivity.class), 0);

// To support 2.3 os, we use "Notification" class and 3.0+ os will use
// "NotificationCompat.Builder" class.
if (currentapiVersion < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
notification = new Notification(icon, message, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, appname, message,
    contentIntent);
notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notificationManager.notify(0, notification);

} else {
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
    context);
notification = builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
    .setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(appname).setWhen(0)
    .setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle(appname)
    .setContentText(message).build();

notificationManager.notify(0 , notification);
}
}
```

Hope this helps.